# Why does QGIS raster calculations interfere with grid cells?

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, spatial-statistics

I am working with some simple raster data on population counts in Nigeria in QGIS. I have two rasters, one for each gender, structured in 100x100m grid cells across the entirety of Nigeria. Each cell contains the number of men/women in that area. The rasters look like this:
[image]

My goal is to calculate the grid cell level sex ratio, which means that I divide the number of men with the total number of people. However, when I perform this calculation in the raster calculator , the entire raster structure changes. Instead of 100x100m grid cell values, the values are given on much higher unit level.

[image]

I'm not sure what goes wrong here. The calculation should be relatively simple, but the results are not given on a grid cell level. I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Have you checked that both rasters have the same resolution? Try to specify the spatial extent and resolution from one of the layers.

Comment: I am pretty sure that both rasters have the same pixel size and spatial extent. Both datasets were downloaded from WorldPop (f_20 and m_20 respectively)(https://hub.worldpop.org/geodata/summary?id=16883)

Comment: Your raster are most probably derived from data aggregated at that a higher level and your calculation is highlighting that. Your result seem to be close to this : https://www.alamy.com/nigeria-higt-detailed-map-with-subdivisions-administrative-map-of-nigeria-with-districts-and-cities-name-colored-by-states-and-administrative-distri-image384553326.html, this is probably the smallest administrative area for witch your original source was able to get population data. If you try to display your two original raster with unique value you will probably get the same "aggregating" effect…

Comment: I think @J.R was right, `Once formatted to a standard table schema, subnational age and sex structure data were then joined on a country-by-country basis, using a GIS system, to their corresponding spatial boundaries; with the latter representing the administrative unit level at which the data were assembled.` from the mapping method cited in the datasets.